# How do I uninstall Tuxera NTFS?

Tags: macos, ntfs

I wanted to remove the NTFS support I installed using Tuxera NTFS. When I checked out my preference pane, the option seems to have been greyed out. How do I uninstall it now?[image]

I tried disabling it but still the "Uninstall Tuxera NTFS" was only greyed out.

Running - macOS 10.12

Comment: Pure guess - the script needed to uninstall is missing. Try Installing the entire package again & see if it re-enables it. Failing that, the installer may just have an uninstall option too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The uninstall button runs the following script, located at

```
/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_txantfs.fs/Contents/Resources/Support/uninstall-package.sh
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$0" != "/bin/uninstall-for-real" ]; then
    echo "Reexecuting script from memory."
    /bin/bash -c "`cat \"$0\"`" "/bin/uninstall-for-real" "$@"; exit $?
else
    echo "In-memory execution active."
fi

DRIVERNAME="Tuxera NTFS"
PACKAGENAME="TuxeraNTFS"
PACKAGENAME_COMPAT="TuxeraNTFS_compat"
PACKAGEID="com.tuxera.pkg.Tuxera_NTFS"
PACKAGEID_COMPAT="com.tuxera.pkg.Tuxera_NTFS_compat"
FSBUNDLENAME="fusefs_txantfs"
FSBUNDLEDIR="/Library/Filesystems/${FSBUNDLENAME}.fs"
COMPAT_FSBUNDLEDIR="/System/Library/Filesystems/${FSBUNDLENAME}.fs"
PREFPANEDIR="/Library/PreferencePanes/${DRIVERNAME}.prefPane"
STARTUPITEMDIR="/Library/StartupItems/${PACKAGENAME}UnmountHelper"
DISK_MANAGER_DIR="/Applications/Tuxera Disk Manager.app"
OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH="/Library/Receipts/${PACKAGENAME}.pkg"
OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH="${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Archive.bom"
OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH="/Library/Receipts/${PACKAGENAME_COMPAT}.pkg"
OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH="${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Archive.bom"
NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH="/var/db/receipts/${PACKAGEID}.bom"
NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH="/var/db/receipts/${PACKAGEID}.plist"
NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH="/var/db/receipts/${PACKAGEID_COMPAT}.bom"
NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH="/var/db/receipts/${PACKAGEID_COMPAT}.plist"
APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH="/Library/Application Support/Tuxera NTFS"
BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH="${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}/Receipt.bom"
BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH="${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}/Receipt_compat.bom"

error() {
    echo "There were errors... aborting."
    exit 1
}

checkForErrors() {
    _ERRVAL=$1
    if [ ! "${_ERRVAL}" -eq 0 ]; then error; fi
}

EFFECTIVE_UID=${EUID} #`id -u`
if [ ${EFFECTIVE_UID} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Not running as root! (UID: ${UID} EUID: ${EUID})"
    exit 100
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    RECEIPT="${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}"
elif [ -f "${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    RECEIPT="${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}"
elif [ -f "${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    RECEIPT="${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}"
else
    echo "None of the possible receipt paths were found... aborting."
    exit 101
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    COMPAT_RECEIPT="${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
elif [ -f "${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    COMPAT_RECEIPT="${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
elif [ -f "${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    COMPAT_RECEIPT="${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
else
    COMPAT_RECEIPT=""
fi

# Store the list of files to delete in memory (so that we don't depend on
# reading from files that we may delete during the process).
FILES_TO_DELETE="$(sh -c "lsbom -fls \"${RECEIPT}\" | colrm 1 1 | sed \"s/^/\\\"/\" | sed \"s/$/\\\"/\"")"

if [ ! -z "${COMPAT_RECEIPT}" ]; then
    FILES_TO_DELETE="${FILES_TO_DELETE} $(sh -c "lsbom -fls \"${COMPAT_RECEIPT}\" | colrm 1 1 | sed \"s/^/\\\"/\" | sed \"s/$/\\\"/\"")"
fi

# Remove all uchg attributes from installed files. If present, this attribute
# will cause deletion of installed files to fail.
# (No need to check exit value from chflags since we want to attempt deletion
# anyway if chflags fails.)

chflags -R nouchg "${FSBUNDLEDIR}"
if [ -d "${COMPAT_FSBUNDLEDIR}" ]; then
    chflags -R nouchg "${COMPAT_FSBUNDLEDIR}"
fi
chflags -R nouchg "${PREFPANEDIR}"
chflags -R nouchg "${STARTUPITEMDIR}"
chflags -R nouchg "${DISK_MANAGER_DIR}"
sh -c "echo '${FILES_TO_DELETE}' | xargs chflags -R nouchg"
if [ -d "${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags -R nouchg "${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}"
fi
if [ -d "${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags -R nouchg "${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}"
fi
if [ -d "${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}" ]; then
    # Backup receipt resides in this directory, so we must do this in the right
    # order.
    chflags nouchg "${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}"
fi
if [ -f "${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    chflags nouchg "${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
fi

# Remove installed files.

echo "Removing package files..."

sh -c "echo '${FILES_TO_DELETE}' | xargs rm -fv"
checkForErrors $?

if [ -d "${FSBUNDLEDIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing file system bundle directory..."

    rm -rfv "${FSBUNDLEDIR}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${COMPAT_FSBUNDLEDIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing compatibility file system bundle directory..."

    rm -rfv "${COMPAT_FSBUNDLEDIR}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${PREFPANEDIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing ${DRIVERNAME} preference pane directory..."

    rm -rfv "${PREFPANEDIR}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${STARTUPITEMDIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing ${DRIVERNAME} startup item directory..."

    rm -rfv "${STARTUPITEMDIR}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${DISK_MANAGER_DIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing ${DRIVERNAME} Tuxera Disk Manager directory..."

    rm -rfv "${DISK_MANAGER_DIR}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

# Remove all package receipt files.

if [ -d "${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing package receipt..."

    rm -rfv "${OLD_STYLE_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing compatibility package receipt..."

    rm -rfv "${OLD_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_BUNDLE_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing package receipt bom file..."

    rm -fv "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing package receipt plist file..."

    rm -fv "${NEW_STYLE_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing compatibility package receipt bom file..."

    rm -fv "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing compatibility package receipt plist file..."

    rm -fv "${NEW_STYLE_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PLIST_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing backup receipt bom file..."

    rm -fv "${BACKUP_RECEIPT_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -f "${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Removing backup compatibility receipt bom file..."

    rm -fv "${BACKUP_COMPAT_RECEIPT_PATH}"
    checkForErrors $?
fi

if [ -d "${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Attempting to remove support dir..."

    rmdir "${APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR_PATH}"
    # This will fail if there are other files in there, but that's ok.
fi

echo "Done."
exit 0
```

Comment: Or as written in their own documentation - http://tuxera.com/mac/onlinehelp/en/ - `/System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_txantfs.fs/Support/uninstall-package.sh`

Comment: @Rene Yeah I saw that path, but it's incorrect.

Comment: Yeah it may depend on the OS version - I guess ?? - I'm not using this NTFS driver, so I can't give the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect path in some versions, so you can modify as this:

```
sudo /Library/Filesystems/tuxera_ntfs.fs/Contents/Resources/Support/uninstall-package.sh
```